# How to read data from vtp xml file

Tags: python-3.x, vtk

I'm trying to read Data from a .vtp file with VTKFile type="PolyData"

Opened in a standard text editor, the .vtp file looks something like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VTKFile type="PolyData" version="0.1" ... >
<PolyData>
  <Piece NumberOfPoints="99686"  NumberOfVerts="0"   NumberOfLines="0"                                
         NumberOfStrips="0"    NumberOfPolys="199368"              >
  <PointData>
      <DataArray type="UInt8" Name="name1" format="appended" ... />
      <DataArray type="Int16" Name="name2" RangeMax="589" .../>
  </PointData>
  <CellData>
  </CellData>
  <Points>
    <DataArray type="Float32" Name="Points" NumberOfComponents="3" ... />
  </Points>
  <Verts>
```

I can read the File with:

```
reader = vtk.vtkXMLPolyDataReader()
reader.SetFileName(path_to_file)
reader.Update()
polyDataOutput = reader.GetOutput()
```

And I can access the Coordinates of all the points as numpy array by

```
from vtk.util.numpy_support import vtk_to_numpy

polydata = reader.GetOutput()
points = polydata.GetPoints()
array = points.GetData()
point_coordinates = vtk_to_numpy(array)
```

**but only with vtk==8.1.2, not vtk==9.x**

Now I want need to get the data that is hidden in PointData "name1" and "name2" as numpy array. I can access the PointData by

```
pointData = polydata.GetPointData()
```

but when I try to convert this with vtk_to_numpy I get the Error

```
AttributeError: 'vtkCommonDataModelPython.vtkPointData' object has no attribute 'GetDataType'
```

How can I access the data of PointData as numpy array or pyhton list?

Comment: What do you want to do with the data ? What goes wrong with your code ?

Comment: @NicoVuaille i want to access/see it in an array-type of way, right now I don't "see" it at all. Like numpy or something that. Nothing goes wrong as in there are no error message, but I can't display the data. I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201888/retrieving-facets-and-point-from-vtk-file-in-python but couldn't find the vtk.utils

Answer (score 2):

```
name1 = pointData.GetArray('name1')
name1_array = vtk_to_numpy(name1)
```

Seems to do the deal.

Answer (score 0):

At this point your code is correct and the data is read and contained in the `polyDataOutput` variable of type vtkPolyData, see here for c++ doc https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolyData-members.html (python as same API, see here : https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/blob/master/Wrapping/Python/README.md)

Then, vtk stand for `Visualization Toolkit` so if by display you mean 3d view, have a look here :
https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Python/IO/ReadPolyData/

For a numpy integration, you can use the `dataset_adaptor` module : https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/blob/master/Wrapping/Python/vtkmodules/numpy_interface/dataset_adapter.py.

You can also convert a data array to numpy with `vtk_to_numpy` module (`from vtk.util.numpy_support import vtk_to_numpy`)

Comment: I'm currently only able to access vtk.util in vtk 8.1.2, not vtk 9.x. Am I right that the point ids are just the indices of the array, resulting from vtk_to_numpy ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple snippet to read the point cloud data stored in a .vtp file:

```py
import vtk
from vtk.util.numpy_support import vtk_to_numpy

def read_vtp(path):
    reader = vtk.vtkXMLPolyDataReader()
    reader.SetFileName(path)
    reader.Update()
    data = reader.GetOutput().GetPointData()
    field_count = data.GetNumberOfArrays()
    return {data.GetArrayName(i): vtk_to_numpy(data.GetArray(i)) for i in range(field_count)}
```

An output example on this [VLP-16_Dual_1.vtp](https://gitlab.kitware.com/LidarView/velodyneplugin/-/blob/releasev5.1.0/Plugin/VelodyneLidar/Testing/Data/VLP-16_Dual/GroundTruth/VLP-16_Dual_1.vtp) file:

```
{'X': array([0.00547027, 0.00558699, 0.00592045, ..., 0.00571808, 0.0055493 ,
        0.00574945]),
 'Y': array([2.61185771, 2.6675878 , 2.60935632, ..., 2.73017893, 2.64959058,
        2.74515518]),
 'Z': array([-0.6998467 ,  0.04656302, -0.60241892, ...,  0.63031285,
        -0.04624888,  0.73556373]),
 'intensity': array([ 92,  67, 100, ..., 100,  75, 100], dtype=uint8),
 'laser_id': array([ 0,  1,  2, ..., 13, 14, 15], dtype=uint8),
 'azimuth': array([12, 12, 13, ..., 12, 12, 12], dtype=uint16),
 'distance_m': array([2.704, 2.668, 2.678, ..., 2.802, 2.65 , 2.842]),
 'distance_raw': array([1352, 1334, 1339, ..., 1401, 1325, 1421], dtype=uint16),
 'adjustedtime': array([1.00010669e+09, 1.00010670e+09, 1.00010670e+09, ...,
        1.00030750e+09, 1.00030750e+09, 1.00030751e+09]),
 'timestamp': array([1000106692, 1000106695, 1000106697, ..., 1000307502, 1000307504,
        1000307506], dtype=uint32),
 'vertical_angle': array([-15.,   1., -13., ...,  13.,  -1.,  15.]),
 'dual_distance': array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32),
 'dual_intensity': array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32),
 'dual_return_matching': array([-1, -1, -1, ..., -1, -1, -1])}
```